# values of an instance variable is different in two classes. Why? (+ more questions)

Tags: java, user-interface, event-handling, null, actionlistener

I have a `TurnIndicator` class, and its method `getTurn();` just returns String of *"BLACK", "BLACK"* and then alternates between *"WHITE"* and *"BLACK"*.

Inside my `Board` class, which combines all classes in the package and make it work together, I created an instance of `TurnIndicator` class, `_turn`, and declared an instance variable `_t` with initial value `_t = _turn.getTurn();`
Then, I defined an accessor method for `_t` - `getT()`.

Now, when I print the `_t` value inside the `Board` class, it prints *"BLACK", "BLACK"*, and so on.
However, when I access `_t` value using `getT()` in another class, `SelectPieceListener`, this prints *`null`*.

Why is it so?

I attach my class definitions below. Irrelevant parts are removed.

What I want to do eventually is depending on `c == _st.checkMoveImpossible()` condition, to make the game player choose between two options -

**1.** by clicking select button(in this case, `_cmi` becomes ***1***, and `selectClicked()` method do desired action for `if(_cmi == 1)` block. More specifically, it changes order of `_t` value, so that the player skips one turn), or

**2.** by clicking scroll button (in this case, `_cmi` becomes **2**, and do similar thing in `scrollClicked()` method to let current player move the other player's piece.).

I made just the `_cmi == 1` case action work, by putting everything inside `selectClicked()` method, but I had to provide `_cmi==2` case(when the player clicked scroll button), so I had to decouple it from the method.

Now, I have been trying to make it work in `SelectPieceListener` class for now, so that I could move it to the `Board` class later if I succeed.

However, every attempt I made for hours failed.
I have coded one class or two at a time, and this is my first time doing projects with many classes. I am really unexperienced at this kind of things.

If you could give me some advice, that will help me a lot.

I know this is really tedious work, but I may not be able to do this by myself..
Please spend some time to read the code and help me.

```
public class Board {
private Structure _st;
private TurnIndicator _turn;
private String _t;
private int _cmi;

public Board() {
    _turn = new TurnIndicator();
    _t = _turn.getTurn();
    _cmi = 0;   
}

public ScrollListener getScroll(){
    return _scroll;
}

public String getT() {
    return _t;
}
public int setcmi(int cmi) {
    return _cmi = cmi;
}

public void selectClicked(char dir) {
    int index = _scroll.getX();
    HNode<ArrayList<String>> current = _st.getPosition(index);
    System.out.println("checkMoveImpossible() = " + _st.checkMoveImpossible());
    System.out.println("_t in Board = " + _t);

    if(!current.getDatum().isEmpty()) {

        if(_t == current.getDatum().get(current.getDatum().size()-1) && _cmi == 0) {
            if(0 <= index && index < 17 && index != _st.indexOfSpBack()) {
                current.forward(_t, current.getDatum().size());
            }
            else if(17 <= index && index < 25) {
                char direction = dir;
                _st.start(current, direction);
            }
            else if(index == _st.indexOfSpBack()) {
                current.backward(_t, current.getDatum().size()-1);
            }

            _t = _turn.getTurn();
            System.out.println("turn is "+ _t);
            display();
        }


        else if(_t != current.getDatum().get(current.getDatum().size()-1) && _cmi == 0) {
            String s = _t == "WHITE" ? "BLACK" : "WHITE";
            System.out.println("It's "+_t+"'s turn now and only "
            +s+" can move this piece.");
        }

    }

    if(_cmi == 1) {
        _t = _turn.getTurn();
        _cmi = 0;
        System.out.println("_cmi if block is reached");
        display();
    }
    update();

}
```

below is the SelectPieceListener class definition

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class SelectPieceListener implements ActionListener {
    private Board _board;
    private Structure _st;
    private String _t;

    public SelectPieceListener(Board board) {
        _board = board;
        _st = _board.getStructure();
        _t = _board.getT();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        char c = _t == "WHITE" ? 'b' : 'w';
        _board.selectClicked('l');          
        System.out.println(_t);
        if(c == _st.checkMoveImpossible()) {
            String theOther = _t == "WHITE" ? "BLACK" : "WHITE";
            System.out.println("No possible move for "+_t+": click select to skip turn, " +
                    "or click scroll to move " + theOther + " pieces.");
            _board.setcmi(1);
            _board.update();
            _board.selectClicked('l');          
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you initialize your `_turn` in `Board` class.

Comment: Rohit> I forgot including the initialization part in here. I added it, as it was in the original code.

Comment: Including your TurnIndicator code might be helpful.
Also the only question I really see is why you get null for _t in SelectPieceListener. If that is your only question you have a lot of superfluous information there. If that's not your only question you might want to clarify.

Comment: You have initialized it at wrong place. You need to initialize the `_turn` before `_t`. So, move the initialize as the first statement in the constructor.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct `Board` instance to the `SelectPieceListener` constructor. It seems like, you have passed a reference to a different `Board` class instance.

Comment: Rohit> I declared _select = new SelectPieceListener(this); inside Board constructor.

Comment: @user25409.. Well, I don't see any such line. It seems like you haven't really posted all the relevant code. Please see if something important you have not posted. Also follow the advice of Martin below.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I see you have some things I wouldn't recommend. The _t and _st fields in SelectPieceListener are not necessary as you can get them from the _board field, why keep duplicated references if it's not necessary?

On the other hand, I see you do a lot of String comparisions with ==, you should always use "STRING_LITERAL".equals(variable).

After that, I would recommend you to use an IDE like Eclipse so you can debug parts of your code. If your variable is null, it's probably getting lost at some point, a debugger will be the best way to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the Board constructor, the order should be changed:

```
public Board() {
    _turn = new TurnIndicator();   // <---- this goes first
    _t = _turn.getTurn();
    _cmi = 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Board {
    private Structure _st;
    private TurnIndicator _turn; //instance variable, null before initialization
    private String _t;
    private int _cmi;

    public Board() {
    _t = _turn.getTurn(); //_turn is null, so... how do you are not getting a NPE?
    _cmi = 0;   
}
```