# how to define a class with an instance variable and methods to make it alternate between two values, and to modify it

Tags: java, function, methods, logic

I am trying to define a class that I could use for my board game.
I think I will use the accesor method(getTurn()) as my argument to the board game class.

When the game starts, it should give "BLACK", "BLACK" at the first two times, and then it should alternate between "WHITE" and "BLACK".
My startTurn() method returns this.

In the middle of the game, after the current player(WLOG, say his BLACK) makes a move, I need to check some condition(if the next player has no move possible), and depending on it, I want to change the order of it.

The methods I need to define is (so we are assuming the current turn was BLACK and now proceeding to the next one)

1) If the next player chooses to skip his/her turn, it should give BLACK again, and then alternate between WHITE and BLACK as before.

Like this : B-> B-> W -> B ->........ W -> B| -> B -> W -> B -> .....

or if the current player was white,

Like this : B-> B-> W -> B ->........ B -> W| -> W -> B -> W -> .....

, where '|' after B or W is just the symbol I use to explain the point where I test if the next player has possible move (using a method), and if not, changing the turn like that.
(I guess reverseTurn() method does this, and this may not be too difficult.)

2) If the next player chooses to move the other player's piece, it should give BLACK(so that WHITE can move a BLACK piece), then give BLACK(so that BLACK has his/her turn), and then alternate between WHITE and BLACK as before.

Like this : B-> B-> W -> B ->........ W -> B| -> B -> B -> W -> B -> .....

or if the current player was white,

Like this : B-> B-> W -> B ->........ B -> W| -> W-> W -> B -> W -> .....

, where '|' after B or W is just the symbol I use to explain the point where I test if the next player has possible move (using a method), and if not, changing the turn like that.

3) Another question is if I have the answer for the above two questions, how I could use this in my board game classes? All I could think of is initialize TurnIndicator, and call startTurn() in the constructor, and assign getTurn() when I pass the string as the turn argument, and call startTurn() every time a player makes a move?
Would this work?(because I am very unsure)

If it does, what about when I want to change the order? Should I then call that method conditionally instead of startTurn() method?

I have been stuck at this problem for very long. Especially question 2..
Any words of advice would be greatly appreciated.

Below is what I have done so far for TurnIndicator class.

Thank you!!

```
public class TurnIndicator {
    private boolean _isWhite;
    private int _count = 0;
    private String _currentTurn;

    public void startTurn() {
        if(_count<3)
            _count++;

        if(_count == 1 || _count == 2) {
            _currentTurn = "BLACK";
        }
        else {
            _isWhite = !_isWhite;
            _currentTurn = _isWhite ? "WHITE" : "BLACK";
        }
    }

    public String getTurn() {
        return _currentTurn;
    }

    public void reverseTurn() {
        _currentTurn = _currentTurn == "WHITE" ? "BLACK" : "WHITE";
    }

    public String skipTurn() {
        ?
    }
    public String takeOthersTurn() {
            ?
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems remarkably similar to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805789/values-of-an-instance-variable-is-different-in-two-classes-why-more-questio). Also, why did you tag c++?

Comment: What has C++ to do with this?

Comment: I'm sorry.. can you cancel the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

> "When the game starts, it should give "BLACK", "BLACK" at the first two times, and then it should alternate between "WHITE" and "BLACK"."

Inside `startTurn()` why not just do:

```
if(_count<3)  {
    _count++;
    _currentTurn = "BLACK";
}
```

While I'm looking at the code (and notwithstanding the below), why don't you just get your `reverseTurn()` method to set `isWhite == !isWhite` and then call `startTurn()`?

Moving on to the questions.

> 1) "If the next player chooses to skip his/her turn, ..."

Don't think 'choosing to skip his/her turn', think 'choosing not to move his/her piece'.  Therefore the logic still works: playerNext takes a turn which (it seems) could be moving his/her piece, moving playerFirst's piece, or not moving any pieces.

> 2) "If the next player chooses to move the other player's piece, it should give BLACK(so that WHITE can move a BLACK piece), ..."

Really?  seems to me that it is still WHITE, because it is WHITE's turn, regardless of which colour piece gets moved.  Around now, I'm thinking that you may want to call your players: player1 and player2 (or playerFirst & playerNext like I did earlier) to a) maintain a conceptual difference between the player and the piece colour and b) not have to go into two definitions of what's happening when trying to explain the logic

> 3) ... Would this work?

Think of the game as in real life. Should you call `startTurn()` every time a player makes a move? In a game of, say, scrabble, when a player makes a move do they always start their turn?  Ie, do they always check tiles in their hand against tiles on the board, before consulting their mental dictionary?  If the objects do this in real life, then it *should* work in an object oriented language (I'm assuming java, despite the c++ tag).   But, the only way is to try and see.  All this assumes I haven't interpreted the rules to your game all wrong resulting in the above making no sense in this context.

Comment: I need to implement these because that was the project description. A player cannot move the other player's pieces unless it's 1), 2) condition, and moving piece takes the String "BLACK" or "WHITE" as its argument. That is why I need this... Is there really no way to implement this??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are putting too much logic into your "TurnIndicator". Skip Turn is just "Next Turn" - the fact that the current player didn't make a move/play doesn't alter the order of the turns.

Also, you have two variables indicating whose turn it is. `_isWhite` and `_currentTurn` both. Just to make matters worse, your `reverseTurn` alters one without altering the other. I would suggest using a `bool` [assuming you actually mean to only ever have two players], and if you need the "string" of whose turn it is, call a function that returns it:

```
 std::string playerColour() 
 { 
     if (_isWhite) return "WHITE"; 
     return "BLACK";
 }
```